# PHP imap - get messages from GMAIL

Tags: php

I'm trying to get all messages from my inbox on gmail.com, but I have problem with polish characters in messages. Here is part of message:

> dla mnie pro=
>   blemu du=C5=BCego nie ma je=C5=9Bli si=C4=99 b=C4=99dzie wzorowa=C4=87 na t=
>   ym co ju=C5=BC zosta=C5=82o napisane

It should look like this:

> dla mnie problemu dużego nie ma jeśli się będzie wzorować na tym co już zostało napisane

How I can fix it? I tried with iconv - from iso-8859-2 to utf-8 but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried: http://php.net/quoted_printable_decode ?

Comment: @Nikhil that's right! THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http://php.net/quoted_printable_decode to fix this issue.

I hope this helps.